# ошибка при сборке Android приложения в Unity3D

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Здраствуйте, появляется ошибка при сборке Андроид приложения в Unity3d, я не разбираюсь в подключении разных инструментов, но думаю что она могла возникнуть из-за конфликта версий sdk и jdk

```html
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:\AndroidStud\AndroidSDK\sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
 at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
 at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
 at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
 at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
 at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
 at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
 at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
 ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает оно с jdk девятым. В Java 9 они выкинули `sun/misc/BASE64Encoder`. На данный момент единственным вариантом будет откат к Java 8.